# UIsegment control with UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented UIsegment control with UItableview. Am displaying UItableview onclick of each segment and in UITableview am displaying json value.Now the problem is am unable to dispaly the value without hitting segments when the page loads.

Function for UISegmentcontrol:

```
-(void)valueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)segment {

  if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"viewcontroller" message:@"valuechanged segment" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alert show];

    crList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:rfcNumber];
    [_tableView reloadData];
    //action for the first button (All)
}else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"viewcontroller2" message:@"valuechanged segment2" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alert show];

    crList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:approve];
    [_tableView reloadData];
    //action for the second button (Present)
}else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"viewcontroller3" message:@"valuechanged segment3" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alert show];

    crList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:reject];
    [_tableView reloadData];
    //action for the third button (Missing)
  }
}
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath as

```
cell.textLabel.text = [crList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Am getting the data whenever i click the segment only when the page load it select first segment default but it is not displaying data.

Comment: Can you please add some screen shots and explain the problem.

Comment: Where is the function -(void)valueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)segment, it should be in CustomTableViewCell.m file and you should assign the value changed event of the segmentedControl either on UI or programmatically. And you can have a delegate of this CustomTableViewCell and have a function which informs the viewController when you want to show and alert or any change in the UI (because you have to update the label's string etc)

Comment: -(void)valueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)segment this function is in my uitableview cell and i design everything programmatically

Comment: so you have a tableView parameter for each cell, rather then having delegate function? best design would be having cellDelegate in viewController and calling the [self.tableView reloadData]; in ViewController itself where tableView's dataSource and delegate is assigned. @ramya

Comment: Thank you so much i got the solution.Actually i added  crList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:rfcNumber];  in viewDidLoad so when page loads it displays the default value and changes the value in tableView according to the segment which i selected.

Answer (score 0):

Make any segment as default,since your populating your datasource on click of segment,for the first time when it loads your "crList" array will be empty hence you don't see any data following is the solution that you can try:

in viewdidLoad method have the following line of code:

```
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = someDefaultIndex
```

where "segmentedControl" will be reference for your segmentcontrol and "someDefaultIndex" will be some default index.